# What's the difference between these expression concerning properties?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It seems like all three of these are used:

- `self[:prop] = 'value'`
- `self.prop = 'value'`
- `@prop = 'value'`

What's the difference between them?

Comment: What is `self`?

Comment: I assumed it's the current object, but it might be some weird Rails thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally:

- `self[:prop] = 'value'` invokes the instance method `[]=`, passing two arguments `:prop` and `'value'`.
- `self.prop = 'value'` invokes the instance method `prop=`, passing a single argument `'value'`.
- `@prop = 'value'` sets the instance variable `@prop` to `'value'` (no method call).

In Rails you can update an ActiveRecord attribute via its named setter (e.g. `prop=`) or via [`[]=`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) which in turn calls [`write_attribute`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Write.html#method-i-write_attribute).

Comment: What are the implications of these differences? Are `[]=` and `prop=` just setters that set `@prop`?

Comment: @LeoJiang that depends on your object / class. `ActiveRecord` uses a hash (or hash-like structure) instead of instance variables to store each attribute. `[]=` / `[]` are often used to invoke the original method when the setter or getter (`prop=` / `prop`) were overridden (although `super` works just fine in that case). Another use case is dynamic attribute assignment, e.g. `[:foo, :bar, :baz].each { |attr| obj[attr] = nil }`.